# How to get double click event on the Google map's marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

In my application, I am displaying Google map having multiple markers. In that I have click event and getting info window.But what I need is, when I double click on a marker, some other page having detailed information about that marked place should be displayed.As I will be having different pages for each marker, how can I redirect to the corresponding page on double clicking the marker? Please help me.

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function (e) { 
               log("Double Click"); 
            });
```

For reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.dblclick

Comment: link is not found `404`

Comment: @PurTahan updated the link, please note this was very old code.