# Google maps API dblclick markers, open new window and add Info

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The global idea: at first user can add markers and polyline. Then he can add Infowindow for every markers through new window by dblclick. But unfortunately dblclick to marker does not work. And can you give some advice: How to make adding information to the marker through jQuery?

```
     var all_overlays = [];

function writeInfo() {
            alert("привет!");
        }

function addPolyline() {
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE);
      }

      function addMarker() {
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
      }
function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          //maxZoom:7,
          minZoom: 2,
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.32522, 18.07002),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true
        });

        var polyOptions = {
          strokeWeight: 0,
          fillOpacity: 0.45,
          editable: true
        };

        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControl: false,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                polyLine = google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
            ]
        },
          markerOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
          },
          polylineOptions: {
            editable: true,
            geodesic: true
          },
          map: map
        });

       google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            var allOverlays = all_overlays.push(e);
            if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
             var line = e;
             line.type = e.type;
             var newShape = e.overlay;
             newShape.type = e.type;

            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(all_overlays, 'dblclick', writeInfo);
```

google.maps.event.addListener("this must be variable where object is stored, yes?", 'dblclick', writeInfo);

Comment: If you are adding the infowindow to the _marker_ don't you want the dblclick (or click) event to be on the marker, not the map?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get double click event on the google map's marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180102/how-to-get-double-click-event-on-the-google-maps-marker)

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'dblclick', writeInfo); - don`t work too.

Comment: Your posted code is not a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there is no map (or html).

Comment: I tried to fix my example

Comment: what is "all_overlays"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I add the double click listener to the marker (or other overlay), it works for me, modified code from [google's examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing):

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    },
    polylineOptions: {
      editable: true,
      geodesic: true
    },
    map: map
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
      var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
    } else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
       google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'dblclick', writeInfo);
    } else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
       google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'dblclick', writeInfo);
    } else if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
       google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'dblclick', writeInfo);
    }

  });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', writeInfo);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function writeInfo() {
        alert("привет!");
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr3E2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It helps me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            var allOverlays = all_overlays.push(e);
            if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
             var line = e;
             line.type = e.type;
             var newShape = e.overlay;
             newShape.type = e.type;

            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              setSelection(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape);
            }
            if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
                var choiceMarker = e.overlay;
                choiceMarker.type = e.type;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(choiceMarker, 'dblclick', function() {
                        alert(choiceMarker.getPosition());
                    });
            }
        });
```